# Plot curve with symbolic axis values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to plot a curve, for example y=1-e^{-x}, mapping the values 1,2... of x axis on x1,x2... and the values 1,2... of y axis on y1,y2...

I know only how define symbolic axis values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$},
        xmin={[normalized]0},
        xmax={[normalized]5},
        xtickmax={[normalized]4},
        xtick distance=1,
        symbolic y coords={0,$y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$, $y_4$},
        ymin={[normalized]0},
        ymax={[normalized]5},
        ytickmax={[normalized]4},
        ytick distance=1]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using symbolic coordinates you can change the ticklabels. Below I kept `xtick distance`/`ytick distance` from your code, but I removed everything related to symbolic coordinates, and set

```
xticklabel={$x_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$},     
yticklabel={$y_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$}
```

to make the ticklabels as you said.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
        xmin=0,xmax=5,
        ymin=0,ymax=5,
        xticklabel={$x_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$},
        yticklabel={$y_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$}
]

\addplot +[mark=none,smooth] {1-e^(-x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.  Is it possible to get a smooth curve without samples?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Without markers, you mean? `\addplot +[mark=none,samples=50] {1-e^(-x)};`?

Comment: Fantastic solution @Torbjørn T.

Comment: How can I remove the last tick on the axis?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi You could set `xmax=4.9` instead of `xmax=5`. Another option is to use `xtick={0,...,4}` instead of `xtick distance=1`. Similar for y.